# Cant trace out cause of error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

why sometimes this code is throwing errors and sometime not ??

```
 if ( getActivity().getApplicationContext() != null ){
    File file = new File(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/img.jpg"); }
```

the above code is inside my fragment

my Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Possibly, there is no activity.

Comment: @ifly6 allright , so how can i prevent this ? any idea

Comment: If you want to check for nulls, possibly change your null check

Comment: is your crash fixed ?

Comment: yeah it seems fixed @Ramesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running this in seperate AsyncTask or thread and activity that has started this no longer exists or active. getActivity() might return null.

So solution is to add null check for getActivity() too along with getActivity().getApplicationContext().

Comment: +1 this answer is usually the case. May also be if the code is in the constructor rather than onCreate or further in the lifecycle, hard to tell with the small code sample.

Comment: Can you give some example  to check this for me?